# How to count a radius of a polygon

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I have a Polygon (shapely) and the centroid of this Polygon (with longitude and latitude). Is there any way to count radius of the Polygon?

Comment: Yes. ___ But seriously, what are your thoughts about it? Please tell us your train of thought and describe where you're stuck.

Comment: I am trying to understand, is it in general possible? With Shapely or probably Geopandas? I found, that it's possible to compute a radius of a regualr polygon(which has sides all equal to each other), but it is probably not possible for irregular polygons, which i have to deal with: mathopenref.com/polygonradius.html

Comment: How do you define the "radius" of a polygon in irregular polygons? There's a different definition - and algorithmic way to compute it - if the radius is the radius of the furthest point, the mean point, the circle that passes from the most points possible etc. I'm assuming that in the case of regular polygons, you also mean the radius of the circumscribed circle

Comment: Well, if you refer to "radius of a polygon" as the "circumscribed circumference", you can easily imagine that this will NOT be possible for irregular polygons (except for special cases), i.e. a polygon with five corners, where three of them are in a cube arrangement and one is far away (-> not all points can lie on a circle). - Agree with @dbouz, I think.

Comment: thanks for insights! What I have found: "Irregular polygons are not usually considered as having a circumcircle. If you draw a polygon at random, it is unlikely there will be a circle that passes through every vertex. Sometimes you may see an alternative definition of the circumcircle: "the smallest circle that will enclose the polygon" For this definition it is possible for an irregular polygon to have a circumcircle, since the circle need not pass through every vertex, as shown on the right."

Comment: Cross-posted on Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange: [How to count a radius of a polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/344031/142375)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases:

- You have a regular polygon, meaning all sides are equally long and the angles between sides is constant throughout the polygon. In this case you draw the smallest circle that touches all corner points of the polygon. The radius of this circle is said to also be the radius of your polygon.
- For an irregular polygon it is a bit harder to get a grasp on the radius. Similar to the case above you could take the radius of the smallest circle in which the polygon fits.